# how do install python packages using python3.11 -m pip

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to  install a python application (elastalert2) which requires the latest version of python on an Ubuntu 20.04 machine.

I have managed to install python3.11 and my searching suggested strongly that to install packages in this environment I should use python3.11 -m pip install but when I try I get:

```
elastalert@secmgrtst02:~$ /usr/bin/python3.11 -m pip  install elastalert2==2.9.0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/__main__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main as _main  # isort:skip # noqa
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/autocompletion.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main_parser.py", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli import cmdoptions
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/cmdoptions.py", line 19, in <module>
    from distutils.util import strtobool
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils.util'
```

I have very limited experience with python and do not know what the problem is.

I actually want the app installed in the current directory and initially (before I realised I need 3.11 I used `pip3 install -t . elastalert3` which worked fine but would not run...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not recommended to install Python packages directly at the system level. It is recommended to install packages (libraries, dependencies) in a so-called "virtual environment".

So I would recommend you do the following:

```
python3.11 -m venv ~/my-python-environment
~/my-python-environment/bin/python -m pip install elastalert2==2.9.0
```

And from then on you call the `python` binary in that environment, to work with the library you just installed:

```
~/my-python-environment/bin/python -m elastalert.elastalert
```

You can create as many such environments as you need or want. You can place them wherever you want on your file system, but you can not move them after creation.

You can read more:

- https://realpython.com/python-virtual-environments-a-primer/
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html

Comment: Thanks, this is like rvm in the ruby world which i am familiar with.

Comment: Hmmmm...  On ubuntu I find that I need to install pythonx.y-venv.  Do I need a to install the package for the flavour of python that I am using for this project (3.11)?

Comment: On Debian/Ubuntu, as far as I know, yes you need to `apt`-install `python3.11-venv` (this is just a Debian/Ubuntu thing, normally `venv` is always installed with Python, as it is part of the Python standard library). -- And yes you need `python3.11-venv` to be able to create a Python3.11 virtual environment  (`python3.11 -m venv ~/my-python-environment`).